# Like Box HTML Snippet for iWeb

Tags: facebook-like, iweb

I have had a like box for a while on my website but wanted to upgrade it to one showing recent posts. My site is created in iWeb.

I went to the social plugins section and created the box for my page www.facebook.com/rivieracoaching but when I click 'Get code'the dropdown box where it says "This script uses the app ID of your app:" the dropdown box only shows an old page that I have deleted - I can't see any of my actual current pages to choose from.

This is odd because the preview on FB looks correct and in the code it does seem to say Riviera Coaching but when I copy/paste it into the iWeb HTML snippet nothing shows. I googled and an iWeb specialist says to copy/paste the code from the IFRAME section so i did that but no joy. Am I doing something wrong or is this a glitch in FB/iWeb?

The code FB is generating is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=124751684204020";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Please help, this is most frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You're not forced to specify an appId to simply include a like box. You can use the following js code :

```
(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And then include your xFBML like box code :

```
<fb:like-box href="www.facebook.com/rivieracoaching " width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```